# Replace a sub-string using formula in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

We're collecting some data in a google sheet, there mistakenly we added + in numeric field and that's near about 12000. Now can't replace this + straight away as other columns are also having this + so it will be also changed which we should not change.
For that how to replace in a specific range?
Here our range is c2:c100001 where we need to replace the + which is a sub-string. Here the data are written like 100+, 200+, 678+ etc.

I was trying with the lookup functions to identify those columns but lost in the logic then.

How to get it done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a solution for google sheet
do ctrl+f then open the option for replacing you will get like the att[image]ached screen

in search select specific range then type like this

!C2:C25278   after your sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

- The easiest would be with a cell formula
- Use an auxiliary column (e.g. `D`) and paste into the cell `D2` the formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C100001,"+",""))`
- [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en) searches for a substring and replaces it through another one + in you case you want to replace "+" though nothing, that is ""
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) allows you to apply the formula to a range rather than a single cell